# CentOS - commands in rc.local not run

Tags: linux, centos, boot

My /etc/rc.local script is quite simple, like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

touch /root/test1
touch /var/lock/subsys/local

touch /root/test2
modprobe -r ftdi_sio
modprobe ftdi_sio vendor=0x0403 product=0x6015

touch /root/test3
cd /root/IPNHost
./IPNHost
touch /root/test4
```

I don't understand why IPNHost c program is not being run in this case. 
It runs perfectly fine when I run rc.local from the command prompt, like this:

```
/etc/rc.local
```

This is CentOS 6.5.

UPDATE: I tried adding debug statements to see whether rc.local was really executed. 
I have all 4, test1, test2, test3, test4 in my root directory. 
What's happening here?

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783341/run-script-with-rc-local-script-works-but-not-at-boot

Comment: Yeah, I've tried a lot of things, but nothing works!

Comment: Does this program check that it is run as `root`? Have you tried running it as root yourself from `/bin/sh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the IPNHost program was dependent on intel ipp libraries environment variables for which the location was not specified at that point of time during boot.

Did a script autoStart.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
cd /root/IPNHost
./IPNHost
```

The source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64 loads the required intel environment variables which specify where to find the dynamically loaded libraries.

In rc.local I then called autoStart.sh, this works.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using centOS 7 you also have to enable the rc-local service in systemd.

Comment: It's 6.5 , I trying to write a init.d script instead to launch the process now...

Comment: so did you try to put rc.local in /etc/rc.d/ and create symlink to it in /etc/ ?

Comment: Yup I tried all the stuff in the other similar threads... not sure why it doesn't work. Maybe programs in rc.local have to end when the initialization ends? putting it in ~/.bashrc works better (still not perfect) but that's not what I want.

Comment: a bit strange but is there an 'S' script for local in the runlevel you are booting into?

Comment: What's a 'S' script? Sorry... I'm at runlevel 3

Comment: /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/@S99local and should be a valid symlink to S99local -> ../rc.local

Answer (score 4):

Due to systemd introduced in CentOS 7, the /etc/rc.d/rc.local not enabled by default, you should make /etc/rc.d/rc.local executable by your hand.

Just run

```
chmod a+x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Answer extracted from [this post](https://www.netroby.com/view/3692).